# Asp.net Routing 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

How can make multiple url of one page in routing in asp.net 4.0?

example -: I have 4 parameters  1.Sector, 2.Area, 3.City, 4.Date

So I have lot of url

```
jobs/Sector,
jobs/Area,
jobs/City,
jobs/Date,
jobs/Sector/City,
jobs/Sector/Area/City etc.
```

And all these url handle one page(`~/jobSearch.aspx`)

So it should be handle bookmark and doesn't create any ambiguity between them?

Comment: But how does your code know what you're getting?? If you get an URL `/jobs/NewYork` - how do you know whether `NewYork` is a city, sector or area?? I don't see how this mapping will ever work properly - you might need to rethink your URL design....

Comment: @marc_s, in general, I agree with your suggestion for URL re-design but this scheme may work with some intelligent/heuristic mapping - for example, a term 'NewYork' could be matched to see if its area or sector or city. If it's both area and city then one can show results for both (or pick up one based on some ranking - say heuristic data such as popularity in search). Said all that, I doubt if OP has such a thing in mind!

Comment: @VinayC: true - you could have some heuristics in place - but is `NewYork` an area or a city?? The current URL design is just leaves too much room for interpretation - not specific / clear enough in my opinion....

Comment: abjectly marc_s  my question is same how can we match New york is city ,area or sector because i have to implement if user search job  job/media/newyork/23-02-2011 so route should be matched and that page should be handled  if u have any suggestion pls give me thank u

Comment: @HemantUpadhyay, you should configure route so that all URLs in form job/* should get routed to your page. In the page code, you need to parse the URL by your-self to do the mapping because you need very flexible mapping. For example, if only one term is specified in the URL then you need to determine if the term is city/area/sector (say, by looking up if existing city/area/sector matches with the same).

Comment: thanks Vinay_c and Marc_s for giving your valuable suggestion

Answer (score 0):

For variable-length routes you can make use of the catch all principle like following

```
routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{*catchall}",
   new { controller = "JobSearch", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WebForms and not MVC, [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx) is a guide.